# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Can not open a record form although seen in grid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I can see a record in the entity grid but when I click the record to open it's form I get an error saying "The record is not available.  The requested record was not found, or that your display privileges are insufficient." 
(since my system is in Hebrew-I hope my translation is precise)
I am the System Manger (as per CRM privileges).

After checking the server I realized an SQL error warning in the Event Viewer:

```html
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>3</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-05-25T18:00:30.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>5574520</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>ServerName</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>3005</Data> 
  <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data> 
  <Data>25/05/2015 21:00:30</Data> 
  <Data>25/05/2015 18:00:30</Data> 
  <Data>cb25f0437bee49deaf1ed75e627b9dda</Data> 
  <Data>30028</Data> 
  <Data>6</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-4-130770366125068492</Data> 
  <Data>Full</Data> 
  <Data>/</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\</Data> 
  <Data>ServerName</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>1428</Data> 
  <Data>w3wp.exe</Data> 
  <Data>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</Data> 
  <Data>CrmException</Data> 
  <Data>contact With Id = 69fa903e-f865-df11-b4ad-001ec9e8be31 Does Not Exist at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.RetrieveCommand.Execute() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String[] columns, Guid auditingTransactionId, Boolean addRequiredColumns) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String[] columns, Guid auditingTransactionId) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String columnSet, Guid auditingTransactionId) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String columnSet) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.AppForm.FormLoadEvent() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.AppForm.RaiseDataEvent(FormEventId eventId) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.EndUserForm.Initialize(Entity entity) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.CustomizableForm.Execute(Entity entity, FormDescriptor fd) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.PageHandlers.ContactRecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormHandler() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.PageHandlers.RecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormWrapper() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Utility.GenericEventProcessor.RaiseEvent(String eventName) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.PageManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</Data> 
  <Data>http://ServerName/OrgName/userdefined/edit.aspx?_gridType=2&etc=2&id={69FA903E-F865-DF11-B4AD-001EC9E8BE31}&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1432576830146&rskey=882919810</Data> 
  <Data>/OrgName/userdefined/edit.aspx</Data> 
  <Data>192.168.30.4</Data> 
  <Data>Domain User</Data> 
  <Data>True</Data> 
  <Data>NTLM</Data> 
  <Data>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</Data> 
  <Data>116</Data> 
  <Data>NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE</Data> 
  <Data>False</Data> 
  <Data>at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.RetrieveCommand.Execute() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String[] columns, Guid auditingTransactionId, Boolean addRequiredColumns) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String[] columns, Guid auditingTransactionId) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String columnSet, Guid auditingTransactionId) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Retrieve(String columnSet) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.AppForm.FormLoadEvent() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.AppForm.RaiseDataEvent(FormEventId eventId) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.EndUserForm.Initialize(Entity entity) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.CustomizableForm.Execute(Entity entity, FormDescriptor fd) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.PageHandlers.ContactRecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormHandler() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.PageHandlers.RecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormWrapper() at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Utility.GenericEventProcessor.RaiseEvent(String eventName) at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.PageManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I can not delete the record nor Deactivate it !
Now I relized I have a few more such records, and all I want is to filter them out an get rid of them for good !!
Please some help :(

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the database to see if the record does not actually exist.

E.g. search on the contact table for contactid = '69fa903e-f865-df11-b4ad-001ec9e8be31'.

If it returns a result, then the record definitely exists. If not then it doesn't. Either way something weird is going on. If you can demonstrate either, I would raise a ticket with Microsoft.

Also worth considering if you have any customisations, that might be interfering with the normal behavior of CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Thanx James :)

You have actually gave me a great hint.

After observing the database I realized that these specific records were present in the ContactsBase table but for some reason (cant figure why) these same record IDs where missing in ContactsExtended.

That is why on the main view I was able to see these records (the view consisted of only fields from ContactsBase) but when actually opening the form it failed!

So creating these records with the missing IDs, in the ContactsExtended table - using the EXCEPT statement (see http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2008/compare-tables/) - did the work :)